# gcc allocate float into stack and not global rdata

Tags: c++, gcc, stack

I would like to have my float variable to allocate inside the stack and not in the rdata section.

The code:

```
   float f1 = 1.0f;
   if (f1 > 100.0f)
```

This will generate the number "100.0f" into the rdata section.

How can i make gcc to allocate this number into the stack instead of global?

Comment: Please share a fully reproducible example with a gcc command line you're using.

Comment: 100.0f is const, of source it's in rdata. What do you expect?

Comment: which platform is that? in many architectures that may well be simply an immediate embedded in the instruction

Comment: thats exactly what i want, instead of allocating it in the section rdata, i want it to allocate it in the stack OR in an instruction.

Comment: (a) What difference does it make, and (b) the compiler does what it thinks is best.  If you want to second-guess the compiler, you can either revise its code generation or write in assembler.  There's no way I can think of that the location of the value 100.0f will make any difference to a standard-conforming program.  Indeed, most programs will be hard pressed to tell anything about the location of 100.0f.